# what does casting object type from 'System.String[]' to type 'System.IConvertible' error mean

Tags: c#

I am quite new to C# and I was trying to write a code to practice about a calculator. It would ask if you would want to divide, multiply, subtract, or add. The calculator would ask how many numbers will be in the equation and, solve it. I know that the code could be a lot neater, but since this is just practice, I did not make it very neat or efficient. Here is the code and error message

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'"
> Line 20 ("int number4 = Convert.ToInt32(number3);

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the calculator! Enter 1 if you want to multiply. 2 if you want to divide. 3 if you want to add and 4 if you want to subtract");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        int number;
        number = Convert.ToInt32(input);
        int newnumber = 0;
        if (number == 1) {
            Console.WriteLine("How many numbers will there be in this multiplication equation?");
            string multiplication = Console.ReadLine();
            int number2;
            number2 = Convert.ToInt32(multiplication);
            string[] number3 = new string[number2];
            int number4 = Convert.ToInt32(number3);
            do {
                int newnumber2 = newnumber;
                newnumber2++;
                newnumber = newnumber2;
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter in your" + newnumber2 + "st number");
                int arrayNum = number4;
                int[] equationNumbers = new int[number4];
                string input2;
                input2 = Console.ReadLine();
                int input3;
                input3 = Convert.ToInt32(input2);
                equationNumbers[arrayNum] = input3;
                arrayNum--;
            } while (newnumber >= number4);
        } //if statement bracket
    }
}
```

Also I think the bottom part of the code isn't correct because I was slightly confused on how to take in the input number and put it into an array

Comment: "*I am quite new to V#*". Wow, I am so new that I have never heard about V#.

Comment: I meant to say c#

Comment: @PoulBak There's an Edit link right below the tags you can click on...

Comment: @HereticMonkey: A little humor does no harm :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to convert a string[] to an int. There's no way to do that, so the compiler doesn't know how to handle that either.

IConvertible is an [interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) implemented on various data types. If you take a look at the methods provided by this [IConvertible interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible?view=net-6.0), you'll see that there's no method for converting a string[] to an int. In other words: the string[] is not convertible.

You might wanna read more about [casting and type conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you cant convert an array of strings to an int. However you can convert a string to an int. Your code is full of bugs and wont run event if you were able fix this problem you have around 5 more down the line. I would recommend that you take a debugger and step though your code and look at what the values become. If you are using visual studio this [video](https://youtu.be/bn1ZJxAM1zw) is really great (just ignore the part about unity)

Comment: i just wrote this code in a c# compiler(https://dotnetfiddle.net/), but can you state the errors in the code?

Comment: Your are never collecting the numbers to multiply is probably the biggest one. Since you havent written that much you should just scrap all the code and start again from scratch and try to step though the program in your head

Comment: oh, yeah I have not gotten to that part yet :\ I am basically trying to collect all the numbers

Comment: i prob should start over lol